# Why does Chromium take up 1 GB in my .config and can I reduce that size?

Tags: chromium, disk-usage

My `/home/myname/.config/chromium/Default` folder has a size of 1.3 GB. Most of that, 900 MB in `.../File System`. Almost all of that is in `.../033/p/00`, in the files `00000006`, `00000002`, `00000000` and with a slightly smaller size `00000004`.

Have any of you had a similar situation, and if so, how did you deal with it? I am thinking of switching to Firefox but first I'd like to understand and deal with the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The `File System` folder is the storage for the [FileSystem API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem), which lets websites and Chrome extensions store files inside your browser.

According to ["Hard Drive filling up? Check Chrome's File System folder" on Ghacks](https://www.ghacks.net/2015/06/24/hard-drive-filling-up-check-chromes-file-system-folder/), it can be cleared with this procedure:

> **Warning:** note that this will sign you out of nearly all websites and lose all data that websites store inside your browser, so you can, for example, lose some documents or saved games on some sites if they store those inside your browser instead of on their web server.

1. Go to the URI `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData`.
2. Select *All time* for *Time range*.
3. Check the box next to *Cookies and other site data*.
4. Click the *Clear Data* button.

[image: Screenshot of <code>Clear browsing data</code> screen]

Answer (score 1):

Mine was 3GB. I ust cleared chromium cache and all was then gone. Try it.

Go to  **Parameter**, then at the bottom **Parameter advanced** and choose **Clear history and cache**.